# Blocking a specific page to Pinterest with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, pinterest

I have a problem with Pinterest : a pin to a page of my website has pushed away my own page from Google results.

I would like to block any crawl or new pin of this specific page from Pinterest

Pinterest User Agent is :

```
Pinterest/0.2 (+https://www.pinterest.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible ; Pinterestbot/1.0 ; +https://www.pinterest.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux ; Android 6.0.1 ; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Pinterestbot/1.0; +https://www.pinterest.com/bot.html)
```

Pinterest Bot IP range is :

```
54.236.1.XXX.
```

For the example, the page I want to block contains "substring" in it's URL

Here is my code in .htaccess and obviously it's not working :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} substring [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pinterest [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(www\.)?pinterest\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^54\.236\.1\.
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: _“and obviously it's not working”_ - which you determined how, exactly?

Comment: Trying to share an URL with this substring from Pinterest
A preview is grabbed to Pinterest
I can see the Pinterest bot in my logs too